# How to filter on a the contents of a packet in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I've got an application that is communicating with an Oracle database, it's logging is pretty crappy so the only way I can workout what SQL it is sending to our database is by packet sniffing for TNS.requests; I want to filter these packets by those that contain the name of particular ie on the existence of a paricular string in the packet. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried the "contains" or "matches" operators? For example,

```
tns.request and tns contains "Marshmallows"
```

or simply

```
frame matches "(?i)marshmallows"
```

The first example looks for TNS requests which contain the case-sensitive string "Marshmallows". The second example looks for "marshmallows" anywhere in any frame, ignoring case. ("contains" does simple string matching; "matches" lets you use PCRE modifiers).

---

Update: In Wireshark 2.6 and later "matches" is case-insensitive by default. You can use the "(?-i)" PCRE modifier to force case sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be something simple, cheers that was exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

There are several interpretations of your question:

1. You're using WireShark and want to do more sophisticated filtering to better analyze the data.  in that case, read the [docs](http://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters).  You can also program filters in [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), if you need extra expressive power.
2. You want to filter those packets out; ie, an application-level firewall or [NIDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_intrusion_detection_system).  Check [L7-filter](http://l7-filter.clearfoundation.com/) for firewall/shaping, or [Snort](http://www.snort.org/) for NIDS (the latter can also use some Lua scripts, i think)
3. You wan to capture packets to log, create statistics or any other automated task.  check [tcpdump / libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) and/or my own [libpcap binding for Lua](http://github.com/javierguerragiraldez/pcaplua).

Comment: Yeah I've read the docs, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. All I want to do is add a filter to find a strind in the raw packet data. I do a search on the TNS.request filtered data, but that just jumps through each packet where the string appears. Sorry, I thought that this would be a really bit of syntax.